# html5 array canvas image trouble

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I just want to make a simple **slide presentation**, but doesn't work.
Even I put:

```
var mycars=new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";
alert(mycars[0]);
```

But it doesn't alert.
Can someone help me 
with the code? What problem

I  think the problem is the array obj.
Please help!!quick!!thank you all!!!

```
<html>

<head>
<title></title>

<script language="javascript">
//start from img[0]
var imgNum = 0;
var currentImg = 0;
var img = new Array();
var canvas = document.getElementById('canv');
canvas.width = 500;//document.body.clientWidth
canvas.height = 500;//document.body.clientHeight

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function loadImg(){
        alert("loadimg work");
        img[imgNum] = new Image();
        img[imgNum].addEventListener('load', eventLoaded, false);
        img[imgNum].src = String(imgNum)+".jpg";    
}

loadImg();

    function eventLoaded(){
        alert("loaded");
        if(imgNum==0){      
            context.drawImage(img[0], 0, 0);
        }
        imgNum = imgNum+1;
        loadImg();
    }

function clicked(){
    alert('clicked');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var displayImgNum = currentImg+1;
    context.drawImage(img[displayImgNum], 0, 0);
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<canvas id="canv" onclick="clicked()">Your browser doesn't support HTML5.</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please remove

```
function loadImg(){
        alert("loadimg work");
        img[imgNum] = new Image();
        img[imgNum].addEventListener('load', eventLoaded, false);
        img[imgNum].src = String(imgNum)+".jpg";    
}

loadImg();
```

Comment: WHY? I want to pre-load the images while the user are looking the photos.

Comment: After remove, how can i do the pre-loading?